# Como puedo hacer una consulta a dos tablas diferentes y mostrar los resultados en filas y en columnas en MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Tengo 2 tablas, una de usuarios y una de actividades.
Lo que tengo que hacer es una tabla que muestre el nombre de todos los usuarios y las actividades que han capturado en la semana, ejemplo:
[image: Tabla Doble]

Podrían apoyarme por favor?

Comment: Esto se resuelve con JOIN. Indica lo que has investigado, el código que has intentado y los problemas o errores que tienes. La idea es ayudarte, no hacer el trabajo por ti.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa inner join

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE A
INNER JOIN TABLE B 
ON TABLEA A.id = TABLE B.id
```

Ejemplo aplicado en 2 tablas separadas para extraer los **departamentos** y **usuarios**

**Tabla Usuarios:**

| nombre | departamento_Id |
| --- | --- |
| Juan | 1 |
| Sico | 2 |

**Tabla Departamentos:**

| id | nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Compras |
| 2 | Ingenieria |

Aplicas el inner join:

```
SELECT usuarios.nombre AS nombre_usuario,
departamentos.nombre AS departamento 
FROM usuarios
INNER JOIN departamentos
ON usuarios.departamento_Id = departamentos.id
```

Resultado:

| nombre_usuario | departamento |
| --- | --- |
| Juan | Compras |
| Sico | Ingenieria |